# How can I change theme from Button in Android

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a qutestion (pfff)

I have a Button with a Custom theme for enabled and disables status.

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_on_off"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="activar"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:theme="@style/**MY_STYLE_A**" />
```

I want change theme by source.
for example to change text: `myButton.setText("new text");`

```
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_on_off"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="activar"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:theme="@style/**MY_STYLE_B**" />
```

I am trying but i don't have success

Comment: You want to change style or button color ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the Button Style programmatically?

Try this one here

btn.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.MY_STYLE_B);

Comment: hi and yes i want but to change of   "" android:theme ""  
The custom style have two color for design click example :
Enable style = green and white 
Disables style = red and white

and setTextAppearance not work for my

Comment: Maybe you can create a XML file with a custom style for your button and set it as android:background="@drawable/custom_style".  The set change it in your code like this button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_style);